# How to access an ArraySlice’s parent Array’s elements?

Tags: arrays, swift, slice

As I understand it, in Swift, an `ArraySlice` keeps a reference to the `Array` it was made from. How can I access the elements of that array beyond the slice’s boundaries?

For instance, does `ArraySlice` have some “parent” property that would make the following code print “A”:

```
func getSlicePrologue(_ slice: ArraySlice<String>) -> String {
   return slice.parent[0]
}

func main() {
   let array = ["A", "B", "C"]
   let slice = array[1...2]
   print(getSlicePrologue(slice))
}

main()
```

If not, is there any recommended way – other than keeping track of the `Array` explicitly? Or is there some data structure more appropriate than `Array` for this?

Comment: I modified the example code to make it more obvious that the parent array is not supposed to be directly accessible.

Comment: But since `getSlicePrologue` is sheer fantasy and can never actually be written, the example didn't magically become more compelling. If you want another function to be able to access `array[0]`, you'll pass it `array`, not `slice`.

Comment: Saying my fantasy is not possible, and why, is welcome; saying how to do things the way I specifically want to avoid, on the other hand, is just adding noise to the conversation. Fantasies _can_ be written – you did read mine above. I’d expect a more accurate representation of it might help reduce noise from careful readers.

Answer (score 1):

The whole *point* of the slice is that it is a limited window on the array. To speak of using a slice to access an index of the array that is outside the slice is a contradiction in terms. In your example:

```
 let array = ["A", "B", "C"]
 let slice = array[1...2]
```

...the way to access the zero element of `array` is `array[0]`.